# Find the vector that meets the following criteria

Tags: analytic-geometry

I want to find the vector $X$ by the following lines:
$$(1,-3,5) \cdot X=49$$
$$(4,1,-1) \cdot X = 0$$
$$(2,0,-3)\cdot X=-9$$
I would like to get some advice how to find him.
Thanks!

Comment: Write $ X = (x,y,z)$. Then you get 3 equations  $x-3y+5z =49, 4x+y-z=0,2x-3z=-9$. These you can solve for example with Gauss algorithm.

Comment: @André if the third criteria were $|X|=\sqrt{6}$ ( X mean vector-size ) what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Assume the vector $X=(x,y,z)$ and then solve the system of equations.

Comment: Thanks for noting me the typo. :-)

Answer (score 0):

$b=\begin{pmatrix}49\\0\\-9\end{pmatrix}$,

$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-3&5\\4&1&-1\\2&0&-3\end{pmatrix}$,

$x=A^{-1}*b$

$So, x=\begin{pmatrix}3\\-7\\5\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @awllower Thanks for writing in Latex.

Comment: Not a problem a all. In any case, I think it suffices to indicate the method of matrix inverses, instead of explicitly calculating the answer, since Op wanted some hints. Of course I am not OP. :P